# disable touch and click on the items below the Fade background when it is enabled

Tags: android, view, click, touch

I am using Fab menu, So when it is expanded I make the view visible to give the Fade background.
 XML file is like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<View
    android:id="@+id/shadowView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#A1FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/tasks_list_fab_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true">


</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Now the problem is , I am unable to stop the click events on the items which are below the View (ShadowView),
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this two properties inside the shadowView:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```